# How to store an entity related to multiple entities in Room of Android?

Tags: android, android-room, androidx, android-livedata

I have 3 ENTITIES. **BOOK**, **USER** and **OBSERVATION**.

This is a **BOOK**. Just data

```
data class Book(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
    val pages: Int?,
    val editorial: String?,
    val category: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val img: String?
)
```

This a **USER**. just data.

```
data class User(
    val username: String,
    val email : String,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val photoUrl: String?,
    val categories : List<Category>
)
```

Now, an **OBSERVATION** that contains a **USER** and a **BOOK**

```
data class Observation(
    val id: Int,
    val user: User,
    val book: Book,
    val page: Int,
    val description: String
)
```

This means that there is a relation from 1 table (**OBSERVATION**) to 2 tables (**BOOK** and **USER**).

All the examples I found are related to a relation 1 to n, n to 1, n to m. But in this case **OBSERVATION** is related to 2 RELATIONS 1 to 1.

Whats the way to store and retreive this kind of **ENTITIES**?

Answer (score 1):

1.- First, you will need to create an *id* column for your **User** table. The *id* in your **User** and **Book** tables will be set up as PRIMARY KEY (unique identifier for each row in that table). Then, in your Observation table you will change user and book columns type to Int. You won't need to store the object there, just the *id* from each table, those two columns will be set up as FOREIGN KEY. You have created your relational database.

2.- To do this using Room you can do something like this:

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.ForeignKey
import androidx.room.ForeignKey.CASCADE
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "Book")
data class Book(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "author") val author: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "pages") val pages: Int?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "editorial") val editorial: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "category") val category: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "img") val img: String?
)

@Entity(tableName = "User")
data class User(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "username") val username: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "email") val email : String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "firstName") val firstName: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "lastName") val lastName: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "photoUrl") val photoUrl: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "categories") val categories : List<Category>
)

@Entity(
        tableName = "list_items",
        foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
                entity = User::class,
                parentColumns = ["id"],
                childColumns = ["user_id"],
                onDelete = CASCADE),
                       ForeignKey(
                    entity = Book::class,
                    parentColumns = ["id"],
                    childColumns = ["book_id"],
                    onDelete = CASCADE)])
data class Observation(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") val userId: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "book_id") val bookId: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "page") val page: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String
)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is perfect, but when I need to retrieve the Observation and show the username from the inner User do I have to retrieve the user for every observation? imagine a list of Observations that whos the description and the user who made the Observation. @mikeescom

Comment: For that, you create a INNER JOIN when create your query. I give an example to retrieve id and description from Observation and username from User in the same query. You can also use INNER JOIN the same way with three tables: 
@Query("SELECT Observation.id, Observation.description, User.username "
          + "FROM Observation INNER JOIN User ON Observation.user_id = User.id")